# Link between Pentaho CDE dashboards

Tags: pentaho-cde

I have four CDE dashboads and i want to create buttons or drop down selector to connect these four dashboards.
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily do it with the button component and then in the Expression property write something like:

```
function f() {
window.location = "yourdashboardurlhere";
}
```

To find the url of your dashboard just open it in a new window and copy paste the url between the brackets (keep in mind that this url will be absolute).

I also highly suggest that you read this tutorial which I found to be extremely useful:

http://pentaho-bi-suite.blogspot.be/2013/11/drill-down-from-one-dashboard-to.html

Comment: dooms, thank you so much for the answer and the link. I have another question is: if i use four buttons to link to four dashboard, is there any way i can make the buttons like a drop down menu?? Thanks again!

Comment: You could use a Navigation Menu Component for this however for me it doesn't always behave like I want it to. So I'd just stick with a SiteMap component.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the Navbar object for bootstrap framework in CDE and it works!